# c++ how to create a std::vector of functors

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
public:
    int x;
    //create a vector of functors in B and C here
};

class B
{
public:
    struct bFunctor
    {
        void operator()() const
        {
            //some code
        }
    };
};

class C
{
public:
    struct cFunctor
    {
        void operator()() const
        {
            //some code
        }
    };

};

void main()
{
 A obj;
 //iterate through the vector in A and call the functors in B and C
}
```

My question is what should be the format of the `vector` in class `A` for calling `functors` in `B` and `C`? Or is the only way this is possible to have a base `functor` in `A` and make the `functors` in `B` and `C` derive from it? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Are you asking what the type would be? i.e. what the `T` in `std::vector<T>` would be?

Comment: yes!! Exactly...is it possible to have something like that? A generic type?

Comment: A vector will always contain elements of the same type. Thus you'll have to make a base class for your functor, then use virtual functions and (smart) pointers to the objects to get polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Try `std::function<void ()>` and use `std::bind` to each instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to approach this (that I can think of ATM):

*Note*: I would rename `cFunctor` and `bFunctor` to simply `Functor` in both cases. They are nested inside respective classes and thus such prefix makes little sense.

### Type erased

Example of type erasure is `std::function`.

```
class A {
public:
    int x;
    std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> functors;
    
    A() : functors { B::bFunctor(), C::cFunctor() }
    { }
};
```

If you need the functors to have more advanced behaviour, `Boost.TypeErasure` `any` might help.

### Polymorphic

1. Create an abstract functor type.
2. Make `B::bFunctor` and `C::cFunctor` inherit from it.
3. Store `vector` of that abstract functor type smart pointers.

---

```
struct AbstractFunctor {
    virtual void operator()() const = 0;
};

class B {
public:
    struct Functor : public AbstractFunctor {
       void operator()() const {
       //some code
       }
    };
};

class A {
public:
    int x;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<AbstractFunctor>> functors;
    
    A() { 
        // this could most probably be shortened with make_unique
        functors.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<AbstractFunctor>(new B::Functor()));
        functors.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<AbstractFunctor>(new C::Functor()));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please let me know if you find some other approach :)